# Dúvidas com COUNT/GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

Boa Tarde, estou com dificuldade com a cláusula group by.

Eu tenho uma query gigantesca, preciso quantificar os contratos por Id, mostrando o grau de impacto.
Daí, eu dei um count(Id).
O problema é que o SQL não me deixa mostrar o impacto, sem adicionar essa coluna na cláusula GROUP BY. E, quando eu coloco, ela separa agrupando primeiro por impacto e depois pelo Id, conforme no exemplo abaixo:

> Id(int) - Quantidade(int) - Impacto (string)
>
> 5 - 3 - Alto
>
> 5 - 6 - Baixo
>
> 3 - 2 - Alto
>
> 2 - 1 - Baixo

Mas, na realidade, eu precisaria disso aqui:

> Id(int) - Quantidade(int) - Impacto (string)
>
> 5 - 9 - Alto
>
> 3 - 2 - Alto
>
> 2 - 3 - Baixo

A comparação que eu preciso fazer é "se o Id estiver duplicado, então some as quantidades e considera o maior impacto entre os registros; senão estiver duplicado, considera o que estiver no registro"
Existe alguma forma de já conseguir fazer esse agrupamento na query?

Ou preciso fazer no C# ?

PS: Essa tabela é fictícia, na verdade são milhares de registros

Obrigada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução é fazer duas queries separadas e juntar elas:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE example;
use example;
CREATE TABLE impact (id INT, quantidade INT, impacto VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO impact (id,quantidade,impacto)
VALUES (5,3,"Alto");
INSERT INTO impact (id,quantidade,impacto)
VALUES (5,6,"Baixo");
INSERT INTO impact (id,quantidade,impacto)
VALUES (3,2,"Alto");
INSERT INTO impact (id,quantidade,impacto)
VALUES (2,1,"Baixo");

SELECT id, total, impacto
FROM
    (SELECT id, impacto
    FROM example.impact) as T1
    JOIN
    (SELECT id as id2, sum(quantidade) as total
    FROM example.impact
    GROUP BY id) as T2
    ON T1.id=T2.id2
ORDER BY id, impacto
LIMIT 3
```

Retorna:

```
+------+-------+---------+
| id   | total | impacto |
+------+-------+---------+
|    2 |     1 | Baixo   |
|    3 |     2 | Alto    |
|    5 |     9 | Alto    |
+------+-------+---------+
```

Dito isso, acho que seu problema vai ficar muito mais fácil se a variável `impacto` for numérica. Você precisa fazer uma comparação de grandeza entre elas, mas elas são strings.

Se `impacto` fosse uma variável numérica (Alto=1, e Baixo=0), bastaria fazer:

```sql
SELECT SUM(quantidade), MAX(impacto)
FROM example.impact
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Alterei para variável numérica e funcionou!

Comment: muito obrigada!